# bash, extract string between two patterns

Tags: string, bash, sed, grep

I have a text file that contains a snippet like this:

```
[#0] PROGRESS:Eval -- P values for  mu_sig-130-0 =  1
        CLs      = 0.0463722 +/- 0
        CLb      = 0.499991 +/- 0
        CLsplusb = 0.0231857 +/- 0
```

I would like to find the CLs line, and then print out just the number 0.0463722

Is there a way to do this via bash command line?

EDIT: the numbers can change from file to file, but the rest of that line stays the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '$1 == "CLs", $0 = $3'
```

Result

```
0.0463722
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
sed -nr '/\bCLs\b/ {s/.*= ([0-9.]+) .*/\1/p}' inputFile
```

Comment: It wasn't me. Your answer is the closest one so far. Unfortunately, it outputs all 3 numbers and not only the one that I need.

Comment: @user788171 Thats fine. :) I added an update to include word boundary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk for this:

```
awk '/    CLs      = 0.0463722 \+\/\- 0/ {print $3}' yourfile
```

Or if you just looking for the line that contains `CLs=` (likely) then generalize the pattern to:

```
awk '/ CLs[ ]*=/ {print $3}' yourfile
```

Comment: The second awk command doesn't seem to work, I only get -- as the output. I've put the lines before and after the number I want into the original post.

Comment: I've tested it and it worked. Can you post your *original* input file or at the least the interesting part with one or two lines before and after it?

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is probably the way to go, as in the other answers. Here's a `GNU grep` alternative, with PCRE regex enabled

```
echo '    CLs      = 0.0463722 +/- 0' | grep -Po 'CLs\s+=\s+\K\d[.]\d+(?=[^\d])'
0.0463722
```

Comment: Have you tried running this before you posted? I just get nothing output when I run this command.

Comment: @user788171, yes and as seen from the output from the command pasted above it does the job at my end. You are probably missing `GNU grep` at your end?

Comment: So, grep is installed on my computer. I can run grep ok. Is GNU grep something different?

Answer (score 0):

this grep line would work no matter how the other lines look like. (you mentioned that line is unique).

```
grep -oP "^\s*CLs\s*=\s*\K[0-9.]*" file
```

Comment: I just tried this, I added a bit more info of what the lines before and after look like. Your command gives nothing for the output.

Comment: i tried with your new  example. my grep line works fine. I guess you don't have gnu grep?

Comment: Is GNU grep different than regular grep?

Answer (score 0):

### GNU sed

```
sed '/CLs\s/!d;s/.*=\s\([.0-9]\+\).*/\1/' file
```